# SQL: How to select distinct on some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have a table looking something like this:

```
+---+------------+----------+
|ID | SomeNumber | SomeText |
+---+------------+----------+
|1  | 100        | 'hey'    |
|2  | 100        | 'yo'     |
|3  | 100        | 'yo'     | <- Second occurrence
|4  | 200        | 'ey'     |
|5  | 200        | 'hello'  |
|6  | 200        | 'hello'  | <- Second occurrence
|7  | 300        | 'hey'    | <- Single
+---+------------+----------+
```

I would like to extract the rows where `SomeNumber` appears more than ones, and `SomeNumbers` and `SomeText` are distinct. That means I would like the following:

```
+---+------------+----------+
|ID | SomeNumber | SomeText |
+---+------------+----------+
|1  | 100        | 'hey'    |
|2  | 100        | 'yo'     |
|4  | 200        | 'ey'     |
|5  | 200        | 'hello'  |
+---+------------+----------+
```

I don't know what to do here.

I need something along the lines:

```
SELECT t.ID, DISTINCT(t.SomeNumber, t.SomeText)  --this is not possible
FROM (
    SELECT mt.ID, mt.SomeNumber, mt.SomeText
    FROM MyTable mt
    GROUP BY mt.SomeNumber, mt.SomeText --can't without mt.ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Why does `100 'hey'` appear in your result set, it being a "single?"

Comment: I need all the numbers, unless they only appear ones. If the text appears twice on the same number, only one must remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a cte with row number and count rows might get you what you need:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(id int, somenumber int, sometext varchar(10));
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1,100,'hey'),
(2,100,'yo'),
(3,100,'yo'),
(4,200,'ey'),
(5,200,'hello'),
(6,200,'hello'),
(7,300,'hey');
```

The query:

```
;WITH cte as 
(
    SELECT id, 
           someNumber,
           someText, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY someNumber, someText ORDER BY ID) rn, 
           COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY someNumber) rc
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT id, someNumber, someText
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
AND rc > 1
```

Results:

```
id  someNumber  someText
1   100         hey 
2   100         yo  
4   200         ey  
5   200         hello
```

Comment: I really need to look into that ``PARTITION`` function. It works - I take it :) Thank you, @zohar-peled

Comment: Hi Zohar, I had a similar question, and I can't understand the role of `PARTITION BY` and `ROW_NUMBER()` I have 80 columns and I want to gt distinct on the last 72 columns, the first 8 columns doesn't contain PK or ID (it's a view), and I can't decide what columns to choose in the two partition statements, could you help me?

Comment: Row_number() simply create a number for each row based on the order by clause (and partition by, if it's specified). If partition by is specified, then each set of distinct value(s) in the partition by clause gets it's own numbers.
Take a look at this [simple example.](http://rextester.com/OEHZ99221)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I came up with: http://rextester.com/VXP42578
could you have a look?

Comment: I can't tell if that's ok or not, I have no sample data nor desired results. You should probably post your own question, with sample data and desired results.